# In Ckeditor5 how do we get selected text to show font-size in dropdown , like that we have in MS word?

Tags: ckeditor, rich-text-editor, ckeditor5

When we are using paragraph or heading or copied div in ckeditor and when we highlight that we don't seem to get font-size highlighted in dropdown for selected text . Font-size is only highlighted for something that has inline style. Is there a way where we can display font-size for selected text in ckeditor like we have in MS word?

1. Pasted some text which have

   This is dummy text
2. Select the text , expected font-size to be highligted .